# IOS MLKit translate attribution requirements

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

I want to make an application and need to use MLKit translate API.

Let's imagine I want to merge some English words into a String, then use MLKit API to translate it, get results, convert them again to words and display in table view.

In Guidelines the following line exists: "The "powered by Google Translate" graphic must always be displayed adjacent any translation results."

But I'm not sure if I did understand it correctly. Should I display "powered by Google Translate" text or Google logo in each cell of the table?

Thanks in advance.

Tried to look for that kind of information everywhere. Found some applications in AppStore that are most likely use Google MLKit and Google Cloud API's but they don't even mention Google anywhere, so I'm wondering how should I deal with it.